# Regarding the Solution of the Monty Hall Problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I know there are various explanations for the problem (some more complicated than others), like using Baynes' theorem, etc. I came up with this solution, and I just wanted to know if this is a well known explanation.

We look at the problem in terms of strategies. One is to switch doors (S) and the other is not switch (NS). We can decide ahead of the game which strategy we will use.

Let $P(S)$ and $P(NS)$ be the probabilities of winning using the respective strategies.

If we choose NS, then the fact we were offered the choice to switch doors makes no difference, in which case $P(NS)=1/3$ and so $P(S)=2/3$.

Comment: Why would $P(S)+P(NS)=1$?

Comment: They are disjoint and in any trial of the experiment, if you could do both you win. If you did both S and NS you would open both doors and always win.

Comment: This sounds a bit fishy as they do not correspond to the same “experiment”. I think a sentence like “The event $S$ corresponds to having chosen a bad door in the first place, hence has probability $2/3$” is as simple and more satisfactory.

Comment: They correspond to the same experiment, but in any given trial, you can only choose one of them.

Comment: The problem with Monty Hall as usually formulated is that it isn’t obvious, as stated, that $P(S)+P(NS)=1.$ Monty might only offer the option to switch when you’ve picked the right box, for example. The usual statement is problematic because it fails to state that this is what happens **every time** the game is played. Then your argument is fine.

Comment: You could also do it like this. The host gives you the choice to S, NS, and do both. Any sane person would do both since that gives winning with probability 1. But if you ask, what is the probability using either S or NS, then that is a fair question, and P(NS)=1/3

Comment: I thought Monty always gives the choice, no matter what.

Comment: @TheManWhoNeverSleeps Yes, Monty is supposed to always offer a choice, but many versions of the problem did not make that clear, and without that clarity, there is no correct answer.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes that I agree with. It just seems strange how complicated the explanations on wikipedia are. Oh well.

Comment: Yeah, this was the explanation I usually use. The card game, “bridge,” has a similar paradox. There it is called the “principle of restricted choice.” This argument is less easily made, there. So sometimes I think of Monty Hall in terms of restricted choice, but usually I use logic the same as yours.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, I always thought that was the standard explanation, and yet looking at the wiki article you have all these complicated explnations using conditional probabilities, and references like this claiming that the above is a "false solution" (see F1 and the paragraph above it) https://www.jstor.org/stable/2684453

Comment: Some people have trouble thinking of the initial choice not changing probabilities even with the new information added. If Monty opened a random door of the other two, and it was empty, that would change the probability, for example, and switching would be a 50-50 proposition. So the other arguments are to satisfy that confusion.

Comment: This question has been analyzed so much.  Why again?  The proposers answer is the obvious solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This argument works, once Monty Hall is stated properly. This is certainly how I think about it.

One problem with Monty Hall, as often formulated, is that it isn’t stated that $P(S)+P(NS)=1.$ Monty might only offer the option to switch when you’ve picked the right box, for example. These versions  fail to state that this is what happens **every time** the game is played.

But then, if Monty Hall is not written with care, it has no answer.